# How to know app(from AppStore) is still installing and didn't just hang?

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore

I am trying to download Xcode and it says "installing" but has not done anything different for an hour(just sitting there).  How do I know it is still installing?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to tell, especially for large apps like Xcode that take some time to install / upgrade, is to open the Activity Monitor (under Applications > Utilities).   You'll find a process called `storedownloadd`.   You can check to see it's CPU usage to give you an idea that it's happily working away.

You can see in my screenshot, I just started an upgrade of Xcode, and my process is running around 60%.   After a couple minutes (after this screenshot), the process dropped down to 5%, but it still working away...   as long as there is CPU usage here, you know it's still in progress.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you see a progress bar, how do you know its installing? You just take the progress bar's word for it. Same thing here. You know its installing cause it no longer says anything to the effect of "Install" but does not yet say "Installed".

Having said that, i think there's a progress bar under "purchased" (despite it being free).

Comment: The screen I posted above was after the progress bar completed but never saw the status change... stayed labeled "Installing"

Comment: Did it go away yet? and are we talking about the same progress bar from the "purchased" tab?

Comment: From application's folder I clicked on xcode and it installed even with it still saying "installing" on that label in the app store.  Then the "installing" disappeared.  The progress bar I watched was in the application folder on my mac.   Other apps will install completely without this stall.